# Can I un-reset my stats?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Can I get my stats back? I did not mean for everything to be reset I just wanted my kill/death ratio gone.  Can I call Activision and get them to get all my stats back?

Comment: You really don't need to ask us in order to call Activision. We have no jurisdiction over this. From all the neg votes, I assume that stats can't be un-reset using legal mechanisms in the game.

Answer (score 3):

No you can not. It clearly states that all your stats will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

No, I did the same thing and I was 8th prestige. It was a bitter pill but I got over it, lol. In my opinion, it makes your k/d better because you should be much better than you were when the game first came out.